# Custom Search and Filter functionality VueJS

Tags: vue.js, search, design-patterns, filter, components

I was hoping I could get some feedback on something I'm working on.  I'm building an application that is essentially a bunch of data tables.  Part of my requirement is not to use any additional frameworks (vuetify) or any type of store (vuex).

Currently, my application is constructed as follows:

- API call upon creation of app
- That data get's passed into a component where I would like to do all my searching/filtering
- From there the next component is built specifically for Pagination
- Then to the component that builds the data tables.

My question is, since I have this top down approach, how do I build both the search and filter functionality to where I don't have to pass anything back up to the parent components?

I am using scoped slots to pass/inject data into child components.  My first thought was that I would have a computed property that returns an array in the control component and then pass that down to the pagination component, which works, but how do I also use that same array if I want to be able to filter results and also search filtered and none filtered items?  Essentially to be able to mock the functionality of some of the Vuetify tables.

Comment: provide/inject is exactly what I needed.  Thank you!

Comment: I posted my comment as an answer. I wasn't sure if it'd help you before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you don't want to pass data/prop-drill between 3 component layers?

You can use provide/inject.
You can provide a "setArrayData" method to the child components (2 and 3 levels deep) and also provide "arrayData" data property.

You can also an event bus (see vue docs). In Vue 2 an event bus is built in, in Vue 3 it's not.